# How to merge the list of dictionary having keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionary below and merge all the dictionaries into one

```
 r = [{'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir MD',
      'Specialised and Location': 'Pediatrics, Princeton, NJ'},
     {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
     {'Name': 'Dr. Joseph Aaron MD',
      'Specialised and Location': 'Internal Medicine, Short Hills, NJ'},
     {'Name': 'Dr. Michael Aaron DO',
      'Specialised and Location': 'Cardiology, Neptune, NJ'}]

result =  {"Name": [], "Specialised and Location": [] for i in r}
#result["Name"].append(Name)
#result["Specialised and Location"].append(Specialised and Location)
```

Desired Output

```
{"Name":['Dr. Tajwar Aamir MD','Dr. Bernard Aaron','Dr. Joseph Aaron MD','Dr. Michael Aaron DO'],
"Specialised and Location":['Pediatrics, Princeton, NJ','Health','Internal Medicine, Short Hills, NJ','Cardiology, Neptune, NJ']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple for-loop

**Ex:**

```
r = [{'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir MD',
      'Specialised and Location': 'Pediatrics, Princeton, NJ'},
     {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
     {'Name': 'Dr. Joseph Aaron MD',
      'Specialised and Location': 'Internal Medicine, Short Hills, NJ'},
     {'Name': 'Dr. Michael Aaron DO',
      'Specialised and Location': 'Cardiology, Neptune, NJ'}]
result =  {"Name": [], "Specialised and Location": []}

for i in r:
    result["Name"].append(i["Name"])
    result["Specialised and Location"].append(i["Specialised and Location"])

print(result)
```

---

or

```
result =  {"Name": list(map(lambda d: d['Name'], r)), "Specialised and Location": list(map(lambda d: d['Specialised and Location'], r))}
```

**Output:**

```
{'Name': ['Dr. Tajwar Aamir MD',
          'Dr. Bernard Aaron',
          'Dr. Joseph Aaron MD',
          'Dr. Michael Aaron DO'],
 'Specialised and Location': ['Pediatrics, Princeton, NJ',
                              'Health',
                              'Internal Medicine, Short Hills, NJ',
                              'Cardiology, Neptune, NJ']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = [{'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir MD',
  'Specialised and Location': 'Pediatrics, Princeton, NJ'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Joseph Aaron MD',
  'Specialised and Location': 'Internal Medicine, Short Hills, NJ'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Michael Aaron DO',
  'Specialised and Location': 'Cardiology, Neptune, NJ'}]
result={'Name':[x['Name'] for x in r], 'Specialised and Location':[x['Specialised and Location'] for x in r]}
print(result)
```

Output

```
{'Name': ['Dr. Tajwar Aamir MD', 'Dr. Bernard Aaron', 'Dr. Joseph Aaron MD', 'Dr. Michael Aaron DO'], 'Specialised and Location': ['Pediatrics, Princeton, NJ', 'Health', 'Internal Medicine, Short Hills, NJ', 'Cardiology, Neptune, NJ']}
```

Comment: KeyError: 'Specialised and Location'

Comment: worked seperately result={'Name':[x['Name'] for x in r]}
print(result).... result={'Specialised and Location':[x['Specialised and Location'] for x in r]}
print(result)

Comment: @maws I have no idea about your error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in (item for e in r for item in e.items()):
    my_dict[k].append(v)

print(dict(my_dict))

# output: 
# {'Name': ['Dr. Tajwar Aamir MD', 'Dr. Bernard Aaron', 'Dr. Joseph Aaron MD', 'Dr. Michael Aaron DO'], 'Specialised and Location': ['Pediatrics, Princeton, NJ', 'Health', 'Internal Medicine, Short Hills, NJ', 'Cardiology, Neptune, NJ']}
```